# How to achieve a result from MySQL with this table structure?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id  content_id  fields_id   value_int   value_string    value_decimal

351 3           1                       204 
352 3           2                       Western Cape    
353 3           3                       Cape Town   

365 4           1                       205 
366 4           2                       District of Columbia    
367 4           3                       Washington

365 4           1                       204 
366 4           2                       Eastern Cape    
367 4           3                       Jeffreys Bay
```

This repeats for thousands of listings.

Now what I want to do, is write a query that I feed the ID (i.e 204, which is a country ID) - fields_id 1.

Then it must give me a result of a distinct list of all the states / provinces (the value string of fields_id 2) for country ID 204, for instance.

My MySQL skill are on the basic side, so could you please give an idea of how to achieve this in a query?

Comment: Can you make an [SQL-ffidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? I have no idea what you want..

Comment: @naruto I have made a fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bcfc6f/1 but I don't really know what to do with it.  Human language:  Give me a list of provinces for a given country ID (i.e 204) - in this case, let's say the country is 204, I would want a result that with values "Western Cape", "Eastern Cape".

Comment: I feel you need to re-arrange you table...

Comment: @naruto I can't, it isn't my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL statement will do what you want:

```
SELECT w.id, w.value_string  
FROM Table1 o
LEFT JOIN Table1 w ON w.id = (o.id + 1)
WHERE o.value_string = '204'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
Select distinct content_id from table_name where SUBSTRING('value_string',1,3)='204';
```

it gives you all ids associated with your desire info.